# Django: how to disable locale in admin app

Tags: python, django, gettext

It is possible to force gettext ignore "admin" application?
Because in our website we don't want translate admin at all. it should be as it is.
Also it would be great to have some reference for more gettext ignore variants.

Comment: What is the purpose of not translating admin? The admin application has been already translated from Django development, so 'as it is' means locatized in this case.

Comment: because it confuses everybody, we have editors for translations (because it's like 10 languages in here). It confuses me, because I can't see the newest translations, while we skip admin part it always hangs on 83% in rosetta. Also same goes for models, but I'll probably just remove gettext from there manually. just answer to do this please. i don't need "best solution"  in here.

Comment: I'm just trying to understand what do you want. Is the problem that you log into admin site with japanase language setting and you see everything in japanese? Or you're using some kind of .po file generator (which one?) and it scans all the apps and throws admin pos on you?

Comment: Rosetta scans everything for me, and mortal people can translate stuff in there. I just want to have admin application in english only, no matter what. That means I want to hide this admin-site app from gettext. Lad bellow posted nice solution =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've had the same problem. Here's my solution, in the form of a middleware:

```
from django.core.urlresolvers import resolve
from django.utils.translation import activate

class DisableAdminI18nMiddleware:
    def process_request(self, request):
        resolver_match = resolve(request.path)
        if resolver_match.app_name == 'admin':
            activate('en')
```